# Add commas to a javascript countup timer

Tags: javascript

Here is my program:

```
<script>
var montharray = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")

function countup(yr, m, d) {
    var today = new Date()
    var todayy = today.getYear()
    if (todayy < 1000) todayy += 1900
    var todaym = today.getMonth()
    var todayd = today.getDate()
    var todaystring = montharray[todaym] + " " + todayd + ", " + todayy
    var paststring = montharray[m - 1] + " " + d + ", " + yr
    var difference = (Math.round((Date.parse(todaystring) - Date.parse(paststring)) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) * 1)
    difference += ""
    document.write("" + difference + "")
}
//enter the count up date using the format year/month/day
countup(2007, 01, 24)
</script>
```

I am trying to make the output insert commas at the thousands place (e.g. 1,234 instead of 1234). How can I do this?

Comment: There is no real question here. Voting to close as such.

Comment: @Delan, I think the question is real, it just needs some cleanup.

Comment: @Eric Why do you need to add the empty string (`""`) to `difference`?

Comment: I agree with Peter. The user is new and just needs some clean-up in the question. No need to be rude and close it just because of that.

Comment: @Kris, actually, that shouldn't be in there. That was related to playing around trying to get the string to output to a function that adds commas. My mistake for leaving that in there. -- More comments below, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your support guys. I am a complete novice when it comes to coding, sorry if I'm incorrect, but I thought that was OK here on stack overflow. As for the code, I'm just taking bits and pieces of I find and trying to put it together into something that works. The counter is working fine, it's the desire to add commas that has frustrated me. I've seen various pieces of code like the one below, but I have been unable/don't know how to take the string from the countdown and bring that into the comma-adding function.

Answer (score 3):

To add commas to every third, simply iterate over the number converted to string from the back and every third, add a comma.

```
var str = "" + num;
var s2 = "";
for( var i = str.length()-1; i != 0; i-- ){
    s2 += str.charAt(i);
    if( 0 == (str.length() - i) % 3 )
        s2 += ",";
}
```

Or such. Not sure about the math.

Comment: This. Just make sure to work your way backwards in the loop so you can ensure the commas are correct. Edit: I added my comment before he added code (just so no one thinks I'm crazy) :)

Comment: Commented above, but this is exactly what has eluded me...getting my string from the countup timer to the comma function. Sorry I'm a newbie this: "simply iterate over the number converted to string from the back and every third" is totally baffling.

Comment: Iterating is going over each item, successively. Number converted to a string is 12345 (a number) becomes "12345" - a string, so you can iterate over characters. From the back - you start with "5" and go to "1". That's done by the `for` loop with `i--`. And every third - that's done with the % sign, which is modulo operator - which you probably know from math lessons :)   So copy three chars, put a comma, next three chars, and so on.

Comment: Thanks Ondra, that helps. Let me see if I can make that work.